# How should a business communicate redundancy/restructuring to those not at risk?

Tags: layoff, it

I work in a small IT team for a small uk based business. Today, unbeknownst to me and the rest of the team, three of the five members of the team were suddenly ‘out of office’ at midday, with some random message about needing to communicate with a third party supplier for IT support.

Myself and the remaining confused team member get a call from HR and a senior director to tell us there’s restructuring going on, all of a sudden, and our roles are safe, but that’s all they can say until the 14th of June.

My manager (head of IT) is one of the people at risk, he knows everything and has worked for the business for years, great guy, dedicated. Suddenly we’ve been left with no manager, no clear guidance on what to do with all the work or deployments we are working on, we’ve just been told this third party company will pick up the slack.

For the last 6 months we’ve worked countless hours on an IT transformation project with said third party, putting in place a method for them to take on 1st line support whilst we do the 2nd/3rd and development. It feels like these guys have literally been digging their own graves setting up the new IT system and handing it over to this third party. No one knew anything and our employer won’t give us a single hint.

Does anyone have any advice to give? I feel like I’m in the middle of a s**t storm right now.

Comment: The title of the question doesn't appear to match the content?

Comment: "Does anyone have any advice to give?" Start looking for a new company to work for.  It looks like this third party will eventually absorb all of your company's IT work.

Comment: Everyone knows they lie as policy. You should assume they are lying.

Comment: We can't analyze your situation; we don't and can't know enough. How the company _should_ do it is a matter of company policy and practice, which is out of scope here. Remember that your immediate management may not know a lot more than you do at this point, and may not be able to discuss it.  Best advice I have is "hope for the best, be prepared for the worst."

Comment: I would guess, by the way, that you are not personally at risk _yet_ but will be in the not too distant future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like it or not: reorganizations and restructuring are a fact of corporate life. Some are well thought out and good long term decisions, others turn out to be complete disasters (and anything in between).

Best you can do is to observe for a while and see how things are going. At the same its certainly a good idea to polish your resume and start looking at least casually. If things go sideways, you want to be able to move quickly.

You've certainly learned something about how your company behaves. Whether that's a problem or not is for you to decide. Keep in mind though that there simply is NO good way to do lay offs. I've seen probably half a dozen different ways to do it, but they all  have significant downsides.

Comment: there might be no good way of doing layoffs, but there are certainly bad and worse ways. The right way is to be super transparent, as transparency builds trust. Of course, you can't do that if you plan to pull another fast one on the remaining people. Waiting to the 14th of June may improve clarity.